# ¿Como puedo encender un GameObject se encienda cuando los puntos de otro GameObject llegue a 15?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Resulta que quiero hacer que un enemigo aparezca cuando se llegue a 15 puntos, pero no me funciona si alguien me puede decir como corregir mi código.

```
public GameObject aparecer;
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Move_Player>().Puntos == 15)
    {
        aparecer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Cardanada. Podrías agregar las dos clases completas, y comentar un poco sobre la estructura de gameobjects que tienes en tu escena, y sobre cual gameobject tienes asignada la clase que tiene estos métodos?

Comment: Hola Cardanada!! Consejos que te doy a primera vista para que puedas descubrir el problema con la información que nos facilitas. No usaría nunca un Find() dentro de un Update(). Si usas un Find(), úsalo dentro del Start(). Si puedes evitar usarlo mejor con una variable pública del player. No se cómo aumentas de puntos, pero cosas que tendrías que comprobar son: ¿realmente encuentra el objeto "player"? ¿Está subiendo de puntos para llegar a 15? Igual el problema no está en este script. Danos más información porque lo que planteas es muy fácil, pero queremos ayudarte con el problema.

Comment: No pude ver el mensaje pero mi solucion fue, no desactivar el GameObject si no que ponerlo en otra posicion y cuando lleguase a 15 puntos se fuese a la posicion que queria. Gracias de todas formas por contestarme!